# How to execute list of scala futures sequentially

Tags: scala, future

I want to execute List of functions which returns futures sequentially.

What could be the possible implementations for following method:

```
def runSequentially[A, B](lazyFutures: List[A ⇒ Future[B]])(input: A)
(implicit ec: ExecututionContext): Future[List[B]]
```

**Test**

```
test("execute futures sequentially") {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    def runSequentially[A, B](lazyFutures: List[A ⇒ Future[B]])(input: A): Future[List[B]] = ???

    val l: List[Unit ⇒ Future[Unit]] = List(
      _ ⇒ Future { Thread.sleep(1000); println(1) },
      _ ⇒ Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println(2) },
      _ ⇒ Future { Thread.sleep(500); println(3) }
    )

    Await.result(runSequentially(l)(5), 20.seconds)

  }
```

**This should print:**

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a pool with one thread and use `Future.traverse` like so

```
implicit val singleThreadEc: ExecutionContext = 
  ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

def runSequentially[A, B](lazyFutures: List[A ⇒ Future[B]])(input: A): Future[List[B]] =
  Future.traverse(lazyFutures)(f => f(input))
```

Comment: It may make sense to create the new single-thread context in `runSequentially` as a single context for all invocations of `runSequentially` may be undesirable (though that runs the risk of overprovisioning if many `runSequentially`s are in scope.

Answer (score 2):

```
def runSequentially[A, B](lazyFutures: Seq[A => Future[B]])(input: A)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[List[B]] =
  lazyFutures.foldLeft(Future.successful(List.empty[B])) { (futAcc, f) =>
    futAcc.flatMap { acc =>
      f(input).flatMap { result =>
        result :: acc
      }
    }
  }.map(_.reverse)
```

Should do the trick (haven't tested it).  By prepending to the list and reversing, the complexity is O(n), while appending is O(n^2), since appending is O(n) and the append is done n times.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `cats` and `Kleisli`

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.Kleisli

def runSequentially[A, B](lazyFutures: List[A ⇒ Future[B]])(input: A) : Future[List[B]] = lazyFutures
    .map(Kleisli.apply) //List[Kleisli[Future, A, B]]
    .sequence           //Kleisli[Future, A, List[B]]
    .run(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with which does work

```
def runSequentially[A, B](lazyFutures: List[A ⇒ Future[B]])(input: A): Future[List[B]] = {
      lazyFutures.foldLeft(Future.successful(List.empty[B])) { (acc, curr) ⇒
        for {
          a ← acc
          c ← curr(input)
        } yield c :: a
      }
    }
```